# Worse gaming performance after downgrading to 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, games

I was previously using Xubuntu 15.10, but I decided that I wanted to switch to LTS releases, so I reinstalled Xubuntu using a bootable USB with 14.04 on it. Everything worked fine and I installed the latest Nvidia drivers (352.63) but upon playing Saints Row 4 and Dead Island, I noticed a significant decrease in performance.

Saints Row 4 wasn't playable at all, with ~20 FPS. My previous installation ran at ~40-60 FPS with the same exact settings. Dead Island is still playable at 30-40 FPS, but 15.10 ran it at 40-60 FPS.

Is this normal behavior, or did something go wrong with my installation?

Specs:

- GPU: Zotac GTX 950 AMP Edition
- CPU: AMD A10-6800k
- RAM: 8GB
- OS: Xubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that 352.63 wasn't the latest driver and upgrading to version 358 fixed the problem. 3 days of low frame rates for this...

How I updated the driver:

First I added Nvidia's proprietary driver PPA and updated sources:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Then I went into Settings > "Additional Drivers," selected the latest version, and clicked "Apply Changes."

Finally, reboot to apply changes.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)